# Django and serving a php script

Tags: php, django, mod-rewrite, django-urls

I'm running Django, and I have a php script that I want to serve at /books, which is at the location /ci/home/bookSearch, but I want it alias'ed at books, is this possible with django?  I tried using mod_rewrite, but I get the django url not found error when I try to do it.

Is it possible with static files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use mod_rewrite for this if you're using mod_wsgi. Just create an Alias before your WSGIScript directive and it will work like normal.

```
Alias /books /ci/home/bookSearch
WSGIScriptAlias ...
```

Comment: The order isn't actually important. The Alias directive always takes precedence over WSGIScriptAlias.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an entire set of URLs served by Django, and then another URL within those that is instead handled by a custom PHP script, then that's something you would set up in your web server, such as Apache or nginx.  Then the URLs /urla /urlb and /urlc would be handled by Django, and /books would be via PHP.

What you might consider instead is a HTTP redirect from /books to /ci/home/bookSearch.  That way you can have the user type /books into the URL bar and arrive at the correct location, even if it's the second, longer URL.

This HTTP redirect in Django would be as follows:

```
# urls.py
...
url(r'^books$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to',
    {'url': '/ci/home/bookSearch'}),
...
```

Comment: When he said location he possibly meant file system path and not URL location.